# Flagging as duplicate - After someone else has done it & Reviews

Tags: discussion, flagging, duplicates, review

Suppose someone has flagged a question for being a duplicate, should I also flag it as duplicate, or does the one flag suffice? (And does this change if it's a duplicate of two questions or more?)

Also, in relation to that, when reviewing first questions, marking as duplicate can be enough for a review (In my opinion). However, if someone marks it as duplicate (Assuming I shouldn't flag again), and I have nothing else to do regarding that post, is the "Nothing to do" review fine? As there's nothing for ME to do about it, since it was already done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One flag suffices. Once a post has been flagged, it enters the review queue, where high-rep users can vote to close or leave open. Further flags serve no purpose. But do note that sometimes people point out possible duplicates in the comments without actually flagging, so those posts do not enter the queue automatically. In those cases, you can either wait and see what happens or flag yourself. When in doubt, do flag. No harm is done, and in the worst case scenario the flag is useless.

When reviewing, if you feel that the only thing to be done is to flag, and the flag has already been risen, then "Nothing to do" is fine. Other alternatives are: upvote the "Possible duplicate" comment (to emphasise that you agree with the flag) or upvote or downvote the post depending on whether the question is good (and note that being a duplicate is not by itself a reason to downvote, modulo those rare cases where it is obvious that OP is well aware of being a duplicate and decides to post anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure how the badges work exactly; but it might be worth it to flag regardless.  There are badges for raising helpful flags.  I'm not sure if the system counts a "redundant" flag as helpful; but as this answer already explains, it probably can't hurt.

Comment: @JMac Flags are reviewed by people, so it's what people determine. I assume it would still be considered helpful, as it's technically a correct flag.

Comment: @JMac well yeah, but I'm not sure we want to encourage a behaviour that has as its only intent to get badges. Flag if you think it is the right thing to do. The badge is accessory.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'm pretty sure it only works for "helpful" flags.  I'm just adding it onto the logic of your post.  It doesn't _hurt_ to flag something, even if you think it may have been flagged.  If you're able to recognize that the question/answer doesn't belong; you deserve the 1% completion on your badge or whatever super low number it is.  The _intent_ is to help the site by flagging bad content; there just may be additional benefits to doing so.  That's not the same as saying "flag things even if you aren't sure they should be flagged".  Just I don't think redundancy...

Comment: ... should be a primary concern.

Comment: @JMac Ok, we agree then :-)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform While we're on the subject of the badge: Are "helpful flags" for the badge counted as helpful flags total, or net helpful flags (helpful minus not helpful) like on the profile?

Comment: @Omry I do believe its about the total number of helpful flags, not the net number, but don't quote me on that. I tried to find your question on mother meta but nothing came up, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I couldn't find it either. Time to ask them then.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Nevermind, I was confused. The "net" is only relevant for extra flagging purposes (i.e., one extra daily flag per 10 useful flags), I believe. (It doesn't appear on the profile, I was confused)

Comment: I don't believe declined/"unhelpful" flags count against you in any way - including for the badge. Unless you accumulate a lot of them, of course.

Comment: @DavidZ This is probably right, I was confused because I read (Back when I first joined) that the "net" flags count towards giving you more daily flags. "You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags)." - Taken from the last paragraph on https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Ah, no, you're right, I'd forgotten about that. I guess it does count against you in that way. But I think the badge is just totals.

Comment: Additional flags are quite likely to bring the question higher up the closevote review queue, so they're not completely meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

An important subtlety: Be aware of that:

1. some duplicate comments under a question are written independently by users;
2. while others are generated automatically via *flagging* or *voting-to-close* as a *duplicate.*

The system does not recognize the former even if a user try to mimic the format of the latter. The question needs one and only one of the latter kind to enter the review queue.

Comment: So following that logic, from a moderators perspective, there is no reason _not_ to flag if it is inappropriate, correct? (since even a comment saying it's a duplicate does not guarantee a flag)